# Install userspace programs on server without root access

Tags: software-installation, package-management, libraries, non-root-user, fakechroot

I would like to install some programs on my work development server because it is missing some programs I need for my day to day job. I don't have root access.

What I did up to now is compiling the software I needs with option `--prefix=/path/to/local/root`. I then created a script that looks like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LOCAL_PATH="/path/to/local/root"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LOCAL_PATH/lib:$LOCAL_PATH/lib64:$LOCAL_PATH/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

binary=$(basename $0)
$LOCAL_PATH/bin/$binary "$@"
```

Then, if I create symlink to this program with the right name, it will run the local version. However, I have some issues:

- The install folder might move from time to time. I happened recently and I had to reinstall everything
- Some programs use `libtool`, which ignores the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when it finds a library in `/usr/lib` (which in my case was outdated)
- The programs are hard to maintain or update

For the first two problems, it seems that creating a `chroot` would solve the problem. Would `fakechroot` help in that case ? Will my script still work ?

Also, the last issue makes me think about switching to a package manager. I was thinking about portage (from Gentoo, which I use at home), but maybe there are some more suited for my needs. Any suggestion? Maybe a lightweight Linux distribution ?

Finally, do I need to symlink `/local/lib` and `/local/lib64` together ?

Comment: if you need these programs for your job, you should make the case to your sysadmin to install them globally on the server (using their package manager of choice).

Comment: Actually, most of the programs are already there, but they are outdated (like gcc 4.3 or python 2.5 used to build the application) or not compiled with the right flags (vim without python flag).
Also, my sysadmins already use shared directory to deploy programs across all the machine without installing them through the package manager as they have hundreds of machine to mange. And they can't answer to individual requests as this is a large company (I am one of the few using vim as my primary IDE, the official tool being Eclipse)

Comment: You may want to ask a different approach to sysadmins using containers such as docker.

Comment: We are moving to docker / openstack, but for deployment only. My company is very big and runs critical software that can't down more than a few seconds a year. All I need is some tools to improve my productivity on the development server (such as an up to date vim, the silver search, some python modules, gdb...). I also want the flexibility to install any software at any time without contacting the sysadmins, which don't answer to such requests unless it's critical for the whole team / company.

Comment: You have crappy sysadmins then.  If you can justify a need for the tools you need through a paper trail, then the sysadmins should update your tools, as the paper trail proves the criticallity.  It's not this forums job to help you subvert security and your company's proper support channels.

Comment: The goal of this question wasn't to question the usefulness of my sysadmin. The fact is the base system is how it is and can't be udated because we use legacy Linux distribution (for vim, this is the last available version). For extra or more up to date software, they are compiled and installed in shared folder anyway. All I wanted was to be able to do the same to test some software before contacting my sysadmin to install them for everyone. This is part of my job. Also I wanted to know how to create a dedicated environment for that, the same way it is done to create Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it applies in your case - but I use [graft](http://peters.gormand.com.au/Home/tools/graft/graft-html).

It basically allows me to have a tree of installed packages in whatever place I want (e.g. `$HOME/packages`) and install symlinks to their files in whatever hierarchy I want (e.g under `$HOME/local` or `/usr/local` if I have root access). In effect, it helps you maintain a number of custom compiled packages (compiled just as you did, but with `--prefix= /path/to/packages/foo-1.2.3` so they end up in a common place) - and you can even have multiple versions of the same package. You don't create the usual  mess, because you get to choose which version to have active at any time:

```
$ cd $HOME/packages
$ ls 
mpv-git
texinfo-4.13
texinfo-git

$ graft -i texinfo-4.13
$ # symlinks now installed in my $HOME/local/bin, $HOME/local/lib, etc
$ # and since $HOME/local/bin is in my PATH, I now have texinfo-4.13
$
$ graft -d texinfo-4.13
$ # removed texinfo 4.13 symlinks - let's install bleeding edge version
$
$ graft -i texinfo-git
```

This can also be used to maintain the mess that is otherwise going to happen to your `/usr/local` even if you are root.

The idea of using symlinks for package management has been modernized again in some Linux distros - but I think `graft` can accommodate most use cases. It's a pity that only a few people know about it...

Comment: This seems awesome and would actually be very useful for me, however I couldn't find the source code: http://www.gormand.com.au/peters/tools/graft/graft-2.4.tar.gz. I searched fedora, Archlinux, Gentoo and Debian package database and none of them have it.

Comment: @Nicop: Just do a google search - apparently FreeBSD still hosts it (many mirrors - http://www.filewatcher.com/_/?q=graft-2.4.tar.gz )

Answer (score 0):

**Homebrew** is a software instllation utility that's been used for a long time on MacOS, but in recent years has been expanded to Linux as well.  It has always supported installing software into a common server directory (requiring root permissions), **or into a user-specified directory** (not requiring root permissions).  The user-specified directory is typically under the user's home directory, but doesn't have to be.

Homebrew doesn't have as many software packages available for Linux as for MacOS, but there's a good number of them.  With its features for the location of the software and its management of upgrading software packages, it might be useful for you.

The Homebrew home page is:  https://brew.sh/
The installation options are described here:  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
The Linux-specific docs are here:  https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux